# Does setting a post status to "Private" in Wordpress generates a true 404 page?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming, http-status-code-404, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a question.

Does setting a `post/page` staus to "private" will it generate a true 404 page with 404 header? Or it's just a page showing that is not found?

> I want Google to know that the page no longer exists and it's 404.

Settings to private makes the site say it's not found, but how do I know it's a true 404 error?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the HTTP response status of the URL.

You have to look about. Google about something like "get HTTP status of a URL", and you'll find many free tools to check URLs HTTP statuses.

You can also check yourself with your browser console whether it's a real 404 or not.
In the network tab, you'll have the page request lists and HTTP status for each. From there, check the request having your page URL (usually the first one), and see the HTTP status of this request. If it's a 404: you're good.

You can also use Postman to get the HTTP response status of your URL. Or on CLI using Curl and many other ways.